# How to listen to neo4j trigger events in c# neo4j driver

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-driver, neo4j-dotnet-driver

Is there is way that i could subscribe to events from neo4j and listen to neo4j triggers that made using APOC (like add/update/delete etc) events in c# neo4j driver .

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can create triggers with APOC on the database side, but to receive events directly in your c# code is not possible out of the box.

For that you can install a Kafka, and thanks to the Neo4j Kafka plugin, Neo4j can send messages to a Kafka topic when there is change in the database.